# if in java Vs. if in c++

Tags: java, c++

In java we can not use an `int` with `if` block like this -

```
if(5){ }
```

While compiling it shows the following error -

```
incompatible types
found   : int
required: boolean
        if(5){
           ^
1 errors
```

I can understand we have to always use `boolean` here.

But While browsing some c++ code I have found some `if` block with `int`. By simplifying them I found something like this -

```
   if(0){
        cout<<"Zero: never reachd"<<endl;
    }

    if(5){
        cout<<"Non Zero: always reached"<<endl;
    }
```

And it works fine. I know C++ has `bool` data type also. So why its compiled without error. Does it mean all non-zero interpreted to `true` in C++?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Google **type coersion**

Comment: Ohh! thanks, this term was not know to me

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup is quoted as saying `"C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it mean all non-zero interpreted to true in C++?

Yes, that's right. This is an inheritance from C which didn't have a boolean type.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, ints can be used as booleans. Zero is interpreted as false, and nonzero values as true. In Java, however, booleans are booleans and ints are ints: you could achieve the same effect with

```
if(i != 0)
{
    System.out.println("int would be true in C++");
}
```

Comment: This is false, it's the other way around: zero -> false, non-zero -> true.

Comment: @zenith yup, sorry, I'm tired.